# Html TD back to DOM

Tags: javascript, html, dom, html-table

the issue: I have an appending json data to html table
here's how:

```
In a Loop->
var image = document.createElement('img');
image.src = data.data[i].picture.data.url;
var td=document.createElement('td');
var input=document.createElement('input');
input.setAttribute('type', 'checkbox');
input.setAttribute('onclick', 'testCheckBox()');
input.setAttribute('id','testid' + i)
td.setAttribute('onclick','tdClick()')
td.setAttribute('title',data.data[i].name );
td.setAttribute('id',''+ i );
td.appendChild(input);
td.appendChild(image);
tr.appendChild(td) ;
mytable.appendChild(tr);
}
$('#maincontent').append(mytable);
```

After that I got the data I need in attributes,
now I want to understand how can I get the TD= ID , and any other kind of attributes after that kind of click or another, from each td... that is different
Edit:
Function fixed to this :

```
function testCheckBox()
{
    $(':checkbox').change(function(){
        var i  = $(this).closest('input').attr('id');
        var id = $(this).closest('td').attr('id');
        var fbname = $(this).closest('td').attr('title');

        console.log(id + ' : ' + this.checked);
        console.log(fbname + ' : ' + this.checked);
        console.log(i + ' : ' + this.checked);
            friend_name[i]=fbname;
            friend_id[i]=id;
    });
}
               console.log(friend_name);
```

Working just GREAT! 
the new Issue is that.. if I uncheck this checkbox.. I dont know how to remove it from Array!

and another Q: can I make 1 Array and not 2 Like here? that the 'I' will have 2 Elements Inside?

Comment: `this is what I get:` : Where is the `what you get` result ?

Comment: What you describe is expected behavior.  jQuery's `html` returns the innerHTML.  When you click on the td, you're outputting its inner html.  You've added input and image to it, and that's what is being logged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not javascripting the right question, i mean, you ask for the .html()  and not the ID value.

> **[HTML()](http://api.jquery.com/html/)**
>
> Get the HTML contents of the first element in the set of matched
>   elements or set the HTML contents of every matched element.

Try this :

```
 console.log($(this).attr('id'));
```

> **[attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)**
>
> Get the value of an attribute for the first element in the set of
>   matched elements or set one or more attributes for every matched
>   element.

Comment: for javascript without jquery you'd use this.id (Just as a reference, it didn't look like they were asking for jquery answer, even though they used it...)